# PHP: Call to undefined function is_numeric()

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

Every few days, on my WordPress installation on IIS (Windows Server 2008 R2 + PHP 5.6.0) I am getting a load of errors similar to

```
Call to undefined function is_numeric()
Call to undefined function define()
```

It looks like PHP is falling over and over again. Any idea how I can diagnose why or what is happening with my setup? Only a reboot of IIS and/or the server resolves the issue.

Comment: Can you show us your server configuration files.

Comment: Which ones specifically? PHP.ini?

Comment: yes php and IIS server configurations.